# Understanding arrays and iterating through them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This question is more conceptually based, but I'm trying to understand data analysis in numpy.

I am tasked with creating a function that takes in an array 'flows', with five columns each represent a dam location with its water flow, and each row going down is a day in time, going from 1980 up till 2019.

The task I was give was to look through this data array, find the data points less than 0, and insert a NaN for that value in the array. It should also sum the amount of those datapoints less than 0.

I came up with this convoluted mess

```
def replace_neg(flows) :

    non_negflows = np.zeros_like(flows) #Create new array of zeroes with size/shape of 'flows'
    index_flows = 0
    n_neg = 0


    for x in flows :
        if x < 0 :
            non_negflows[index_flows] = np.nan #Iterating through
            n_neg += 1
            index_flows += 1
         else :
            index_flows += 1
    return n_neg, non_negflows
```

I realised some things where I went wrong in that code, but the solution was much simpler than I thought

```
def replace_neg(flows) :

        neg_array = flows < 0  #Does this iterate over whole 'flows' array?
        n_neg = np.sum(neg_array)
        check = n_neg != 0 
        
        print(f'Number of negative records in original  dataset = {n_neg}')
       
        if check:
            flows[flows < 0] = np.nan 
        return n_neg, flows
```

My question is how the second code iterates over everything in the array without a more in depth for loop like I had though in my first attempt. It's pretty cool to just use a simply boolean statement like in the solution, I'm just not understanding the process here.

Thanks!

Comment: This still uses a "for" loop, it just gets run behind the scenes.  Numpy is build on C, so almost everything you do in numpy is really calling a C function that has been *highly* optimized and, most likely, takes advantage of vectorization (that's why your second function runs faster than the first).

Comment: @tnknepp, in the `numpy` world, "vectorization" means "using compiled methods that operate on the whole array".  It's the compiled versus interpreted code that make the speed difference.  The compiler may take advantage of processor-level optimizations, but that's not an inherent part of `numpy`.

Comment: @hpaulj Sure, but I thought the compiler always implements vectorization when the processor supports it.